# putting data from json file to javascript variable directly

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core

I want to get the data directly from the JSON file to javascript variable (data) how can I do it 
I use asp.net core and the JSON file in the root.

```
var data = Jsonfile;
```

json file have this

```
[
    {
      "description" : "twitter",
      "link" : "https://twitter.com/digitalocean"
    },
    {
      "description" : "facebook",
      "link" : "https://www.facebook.com/DigitalOceanCloudHosting"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get JSON file data in an action and call this action using fetch/ajax in javascript.

Refer to my demo where `myData.json` is located in the root of project and use `HomeController` as an example.

1.HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult GetJsonValue()
    {
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        string path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, "myData.json");
        var JSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        var jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);
        return new JsonResult(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

2.Javascript

```
 //use ajax
 $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/Home/GetJsonValue"

    }).done(
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
 //or use fetch
 fetch("/Home/GetJsonValue")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => {
            console.log(myJson);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to *fetch* the file from the directory. The `fetch` function will return a promise. When a response is returned it has to be read as JSON. After that your JSON data is available to use in the next callback.

```
fetch('./relativepath/jsonfile.json')
  .then(response => response.json()) 
  .then(data => {
    // Use your json here. It is stored in the data variable.
  });
```

You could create an *async function* to make the code reusable.

```
async function getJson(resource)
  const response = await fetch(resource);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

```
getJson('./relativepath/jsonfile.json').then(data => {
  // Use your json here.
});
```

Comment: when i make the frist one it give me this error in  the browser console he think the json file in the home but it's in the root directly 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Okay, well. Then the next step will be to figure out how to get the correct path to the file and expose it to JavaScript. Good luck!